# Part of cell bounds stays on screen while try to edit the width of the UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` with grouped style and `UITableViewCell`, which I need to make a little bit wider. So, I subclassing the `UITableViewCell` and implement there a method:

```
- (void) layoutSubviews
{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad && !IS_OS_7_OR_LATER) {
        CGRect frame = self.frame;
        frame.origin.x -= 10;
        frame.size.width += 20;
        self.frame = frame;
    }
}
```

Now there is a problem - my cell looks like this:

[image]

and with colour layers on:

[image]

In the top of the cell there is a part of the bounds of the previous cell before resizing.. This you can see much clearly on the second screen. Can you help me how to remove this border?

Answer (score 0):

```
UIView *backgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
backgroundView.backgroundColor =  [UIColor colorWithRed:240 green:240 blue:240 alpha:1];
cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
```

have a try.

Comment: maybe you can try assign a view with background color like groupTableview